# Google maps v2 not work from google play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I have an app with maps, and it work well. But after I publish it at google play, the map not display.

Once I've put applications with a map to the store, and everything was fine.
Now I get sha1 for my key, and put it at google developer console, and try all the answers about it.

So I think that something was changed.

Any idea?

Comment: generate api key with the release keystore and place it in your developer console

Comment: Are you sure you generated New `API key` from your `keystore` with new `SHA-1`?

Comment: Yes. I think so, at least. Do you have directions, so I try again?

Comment: I try all the ways that I can found. I need something new... I already do it, and it work. I do not know what has changed.

Comment: The SHA which you'r using is in debug mode but while you upload apk on play store it will be in release mode. So you need to create your google map API key using SHA in a release mode.

Comment: I do it, but it still not work. I need to create new API key, or only to update it?

Comment: You can do anything for it. After that put that api key in manifest you must run your app once and export APK which will show you google map. But your SHA will be different for release mode.

Comment: @offset Check my answer step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the steps how to generate `Google Map V2 API Key` for `Release Mode`.

If you work on `Windows 7` then

1. Open your command prompt and go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` (Where your **JRE** installed)
2. Now generate your own keystore first by using below command

   ```
   keytool  -genkey -v -keystore keystore demokeystore.keystore -alias  YouraliasName -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000000
   ```
3. Now if you see the **demokeystore.keystore** file is created in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` folder
4. Now time to generate **SHA-1** by using this **demokeystore.keystore** by using below command

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore demokeystore.keystore -alias YouraliasName -storepass yourPassword  -keypass yourkeyPassword
   ```
5. Now at last step pick up new `SHA-1` and generate new `API key` from console and also add(Register) key in your project `manifest.xml`
6. Also built the `.apk` from the same **keystore** for play store.

Comment: step 2 error: 
`Illegal option:  demokeystore.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

There is 2 files with google_api_key, one for release and one for debug. I forget to change the one for release...